# FOR XML without FROM

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have inherited a 1500 line stored procedure which declares a myriad of variables that frequently change state throughout the life of the procedure. We have a logic error that has proven extremely difficult to trace and as such have been tasked to write the variables for a finite amount of time to a log table.  My solution is to take each of the variables and stuff them into XML and record them in a table without indexes so its as fast as it possibly can be during a write.  This is a bit of a last resort but we have a million dollar discrepency riding on a solution to this and not a lot of time to dig.

So the solution will be something like this for the period of a week when we run the proc:

- Procedure Declares and Initializes Data into the variables.
- Function is called to record states
- Procedure does a bunch more code changing states
- Function is called to record states
- Procedure does lots more.
- Function is called to record states.

My question is this.

```
DECLARE @TESTSTRING VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TESTINTEGER INT
DECLARE @TESTDATE DATETIME = GETDATE()

SELECT @TESTSTRING, @TESTINTEGER, @TESTDATE FOR XML...
```

Can I output the variables as XML by just selecting them like this in some way?  I know usually the FOR XML syntax requires that it come after a FROM clause.  Which in this case I won't have.  If that's not the case... How expensive is this?

```
DECLARE @TESTSTRING VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TESTINTEGER INT
DECLARE @TESTDATE DATETIME = GETDATE()

SELECT
    *
FROM
    (SELECT @TESTSTRING AS TESTSTRING, @TESTINTEGER AS TESTINTEGER, @TESTDATE AS TESTDATE) AS S
FOR XML PATH('VAR'), ROOT('TESTTABLE')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that would work just fine, although you can skip the subquery as long as the variables being selected have aliases.  Also, consider how you want to represent null parameter values in the xml using the isnull function.

```
DECLARE @TESTSTRING VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TESTINTEGER INT
DECLARE @TESTDATE DATETIME = GETDATE()
set @TESTSTRING = 'xxx'
set @TESTINTEGER = 2

declare @outputxml as xml
set @outputxml = (
    SELECT isnull(@TESTSTRING,'--NULL--') AS TESTSTRING, isnull(@TESTINTEGER,-1) AS TESTINTEGER, isnull(@TESTDATE,'1/1/1900') AS TESTDATE
    FOR XML PATH('VAR'), ROOT('TESTTABLE')`enter code here`
    )

select @outputxml
```

Comment: I didn't put it in my example but I will be tacking on the ELEMENTS XSINIL which will just placehold for nulls.  I wasn't too worried about initializing as you have done in your example.  But I should have specified.  Thank you for your quick response!

Comment: Actually that did answer my question. Just tried a variant of what you did with the @outputxml variable.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the non abstract of what I am doing.  Works perfectly.  I've nulled everything out for HIPPA.

```
DECLARE @CLAIMID VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SOMECLAIMID'
DECLARE @CoreClaimTotalPaid MONEY
DECLARE @ClaimTotalAmt MONEY
DECLARE @MemID CHAR(15)
DECLARE @CLMStartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @CLMEndDate DATETIME
DECLARE @MonthlyCostShareID INT
DECLARE @MonthlyCostShareIDRollback INT
DECLARE @MonthlyCostShareAmt MONEY
DECLARE @MonthlyShareAmtUsed MONEY
DECLARE @MonthlyCostShareRateCode CHAR(2)
DECLARE @SOCBalance MONEY
DECLARE @CDTotalPaid MONEY
DECLARE @CDTotalSOC MONEY
DECLARE @PROC_USER CHAR(15)
DECLARE @CostShareClaimID INT
DECLARE @AdjudicatedCostShareAmtApplied MONEY
DECLARE @PrevSOCAmt MONEY
DECLARE @totalpaid MONEY
DECLARE @Message varchar(200)
DECLARE @getdate DATETIME
DECLARE @IHCMFPcutoff SMALLDATETIME


SELECT @CLAIMID ClaimID,@CoreClaimTotalPaid CoreClaimTotalPaid,@ClaimTotalAmt ClaimTotalAmt,@MemID MemID,@CLMStartDate CLMStartDate,@CLMEndDate CLMEndDate,
       @MonthlyCostShareID MonthlyCostShareID,@MonthlyCostShareIDRollback MonthlyCostShareIDRollback,@MonthlyCostShareAmt MonthlyCostShareAmt,
       @MonthlyShareAmtUsed MonthlyShareAmtUsed,@MonthlyCostShareRateCode MonthlyCostShareRateCode,@SOCBalance SOCBalance,@CDTotalPaid CDTotalPaid,
       @CDTotalSOC CDTotalSOC,@PROC_USER PROC_USER,@CostShareClaimID CostShareClaimID, @AdjudicatedCostShareAmtApplied AdjudicatedCostShareAmtApplied,
       @PrevSOCAmt PrevSOCAmt,@totalpaid totalpaid,@Message [Message],@getdate [getdate],@IHCMFPcutoff IHCMFPcutoff 
FOR XML PATH('VAR'), ROOT('TESTTABLE'), ELEMENTS XSINIL
```

And the XML:

```
<TESTTABLE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <VAR>
    <ClaimID>SOMECLAIMID</ClaimID>
    <CoreClaimTotalPaid xsi:nil="true" />
    <ClaimTotalAmt xsi:nil="true" />
    <MemID xsi:nil="true" />
    <CLMStartDate xsi:nil="true" />
    <CLMEndDate xsi:nil="true" />
    <MonthlyCostShareID xsi:nil="true" />
    <MonthlyCostShareIDRollback xsi:nil="true" />
    <MonthlyCostShareAmt xsi:nil="true" />
    <MonthlyShareAmtUsed xsi:nil="true" />
    <MonthlyCostShareRateCode xsi:nil="true" />
    <SOCBalance xsi:nil="true" />
    <CDTotalPaid xsi:nil="true" />
    <CDTotalSOC xsi:nil="true" />
    <PROC_USER xsi:nil="true" />
    <CostShareClaimID xsi:nil="true" />
    <AdjudicatedCostShareAmtApplied xsi:nil="true" />
    <PrevSOCAmt xsi:nil="true" />
    <totalpaid xsi:nil="true" />
    <Message xsi:nil="true" />
    <getdate xsi:nil="true" />
    <IHCMFPcutoff xsi:nil="true" />
  </VAR>
</TESTTABLE>
```